# Importing Lod2 Data into Threebox/ThreeJs as georeferenced

Tags: mapbox, 3d, mapbox-gl-js

I have a project and I want to import my LoD2 data into threebox. I tried this in several way.

- Original data in CityGML format that contains multiple buildings but since ThreeJS/Threebox does not support this data format, I have to do a data conversion.

1. I converted data into OBJ/GLTF format, importing this data into platform works properly, but since I lose the coordinate information I cannot put the model on the mapbox basemap even though I set some coordinate parameters, it does not match (as it is a 2kmx2km tile contains multiple buildings, one coordinate set up is not enough)

[image]

2. I converted the data into GeoJSON format as there is a 3D-extursion method in threebox. I can put the model georeferenced on the basemap, but this time I lose LoD2 attributes like shape of the roofs during data conversion from 3D to 2D.

[image]

Is there any other way that I can import my model on the mapbox basemap, without losing the coordinate system and LoD2 attributes?